# hline() returns with error message in a case. How to fix it?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The following code draws a horizontal line properly at $1234:

```
hline(1234, title="title", color=#ff0000, linestyle = hline.style_dotted, linewidth=1)
```

But if I put a price there (don't mention an expression or even a `boolean ? expression : na` formula) then it returns with the error message below.

```
hline(low, title="title", color=#ff0000, linestyle = hline.style_dotted, linewidth=1)
```

Error message is: `Cannot call 'hline' with argument 'price'='low'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'input float' is expected`

(I would like to draw a suggested Stop Loss level below/above buy/short signals. Actually, a `line.new()` width `extend.both` could be more useful but anyways, this answer should be useful for anyone facing the same case, and practically the same error happens in case of `line.new(low, extend.both)`, beside other obvious errors)

What do I do wrong with this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hline()` expects its `price` parameter not to change during the script's execution. That's why it works with `1234` and not with `low`.

`line` suits better to your needs in this case.